# jquery popup loading slow in IE

Tags: jquery

I have a page showing 100 rows of data and I have a button "Information" in each row showing more details about that record of that row.

It works fine in chrome /safari. But in firefox and IE11 it is very slow to render the page.

My code looks like the below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/jquery.shorten.js"></script>
```

.................
.............
In each row the below code is there for the "Information" button.

```
<a href="#popup1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-
mini=true data-theme="a" data-inline="true" onclick="$('#popup1').popup();        
$('#popup1').popup('open');">Information</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup1" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15" data-
transition="slide">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-
iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><iframe src="http://example.com/test.php?
row=1" width="680" height="320" seamless></iframe>
</div>
.....................
.......................
<a href="#popup2" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-        
mini=true data-theme="a" data-inline="true" onclick="$('#popup2').popup(); 
$('#popup2').popup('open');">Information</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup2" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15" data-
transition="slide">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-
iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><iframe src="http://example.com/test.php?
row=2" width="680" height="320" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

Could you please tell me how we change the above to load faster please?

Thx

Comment: How big is the final HTML code of your page ? How many lines/characters/kB ? You might not want to send everything in one page if you have a lot of data. I also suspect that 100 iframes might be a little too much to handle; try to comment them out ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: Well, it is a big page - that is the user's need. But it pulls up in one second in chrome and safari though - why slow in IE please? Is there a way I can define one iframe at the end of the page and call it when the "Information" button in any row is clicked with that rowid. Need help with that code please.